# tftp server not working on scientific linux 6.1

Tags: tftp, scientific-linux

I can't get tftp to work on my machine running Scientific Linux 6.1:

```
[root@bugs ~]# ls /tftpboot/
default  example.txt  MX075000.002_107  MX075100.002_025  MX076000.002  MX076200.002      MX0779900.002
[root@bugs ~]# tftp localhost
tftp> status
Connected to localhost.
Mode: netascii Verbose: off Tracing: off Literal: off
Rexmt-interval: 5 seconds, Max-timeout: 25 seconds
tftp> get example.txt
Transfer timed out.
```

This is the tftp configuration:

```
[claudiu@bugs claudiu]$ cat /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
service tftp
{
    disable = no
    socket_type     = dgram
    protocol        = udp
    wait            = yes
    user            = root
    server          = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args     = -c -s /tftpboot -v -v -v
    per_source      = 11
    cps         = 100 2
    flags           = IPv4
}
```

xinetd is up and running:

```
[claudiu@bugs claudiu]$ sudo service xinetd status
xinetd (pid  23864) is running...
```

Tftp seems to be turned on and port 69 is open:

```
[claudiu@bugs claudiu]$ chkconfig | grep tftp
    tftp:           on
[claudiu@bugs claudiu]$ sudo nmap -sU localhost | grep 69
69/udp   open|filtered tftp
```

Also, the permissions seem to be set right:

```
[claudiu@bugs claudiu]$ ls -l / | grep ftp
drwxrwxrwx.   2 root    root     4096 Jan  5 15:48 tftpboot
[claudiu@bugs claudiu]$ cd /tftpboot/
[claudiu@bugs tftpboot]$ ls -l example.txt
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Jan  4 15:38 /tftpboot/example.txt
```

If anybody has any idea what could go wrong, I could use some help...

Comment: Note that *chkconfig* does not manage [x]inetd; rather, it controls the **stand-alone** *tftp* daemon. If you have both active, there is a very high chance of conflicts.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think there's any conflicts in this case...I tried turning chkconfig off and xinetd on and vice-versa but it's still not working...

Comment: How about your selinux configuration?

Comment: @kamae Yes, it seems that was it. I solved this problem some time ago, but forgot to close the question. I tried to configure selinux to allow tftp, but I needed the service urgently, so I finally disabled selinux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that SELinux was causing the trouble. I didn't manage to make tftp work with it, so I fully disabled SELinux. I know it's not recommended, but if anybody else needs to know how to do this, here it is: you need to edit the /etc/selinux/config file and change the line containing "SELINUX=" to:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

A system reboot is **mandatory**. Without it, the changes won't take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Check that ICMP is not prohibited in `iptables`. It solved my problems.

By the way, SELinux does not have to be disabled to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 0 >/selinux/enforce
```

This will put SELinux in permissive mode, however a reboot will clear this.

```
cat /selinux/enforce
```

This would verify that it is in permissive mode.

This way you do not have to reboot the machine. Just make sure `SELINUX=disabled` in `/etc/selinux/config` so it survives a reboot.